# try to run traceroute in gcp airflow but getting error: "No such file or directory: 'traceroute'"

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, traceroute

we are trying to run trace route from airflow (in gcp) to get the output

```
traceroute = subprocess.Popen(["traceroute", '-w', '100','10.10.10.00'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

for line in iter(traceroute.stdout.readline,""):
    print(line)
```

but getting below error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'traceroute'
```

is there any way to run traceroute from gcp airflow ?

Comment: Traceroute is not normally installed with Linux. It is an optional package. Since Composer is a managed service, I am not aware of a method to install Linux packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use native Python to get the same result as traceroute. You can use pip package [mtrpacket](https://pypi.org/project/mtrpacket/) and then use the following code. To install a pip package use the `PYPI PACKAGES` tab from the composer UI.

This code will run without requiring root permissions.

```py
import asyncio
import mtrpacket

async def trace():
    async with mtrpacket.MtrPacket() as mtr:
        for ttl in range(1, 256):
            result = await mtr.probe('172.217.160.206', ttl=ttl)
            print(result)

            if result.success:
                break

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(trace())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kunal but i am getting below error 

Failed to install PyPI packages. google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.13.1 has requirement google-api-core[grpc]!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5, but you have google-api-core 1.31.3

Comment: Any suggestion pls

Comment: @Arya that is a completely different issue, which has nothing to do with Kunal's suggestion. Take a look at your `requirements.txt` file. You've likely locked `google-api-core` to a specific version.

Comment: Try it from the composer ui tab as mentioned.

Comment: @KunalDeo . If we are getting error :  "failure to communicate with subprocess "mtr-packet" " -- How can we fix this ?